# Find original url of links rather than the tracking url from google, facebook etc

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am making a chrome extension for pdf links

```
function getD(info, tab)
{
   var url = info.srcUrl;
   var sb = "http://www.abcfadsds.com/?url="+info.linkUrl;
   chrome.tabs.create({"url":sb});
}
```

Now this works for most links but if a right click a link on google / facebook
the url generated is something like

```
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pdf&source=web&cd......................
```

how do i obtain the original URL??

Comment: I've written a UserScript/Chrome extension to disable Google's URL rewrites. See http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121923.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually its a variable in the url.  For instance in a google links youll see something like....
`url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaa.com%2F`
...so you just need to get the value for url from the link and unescape it.
Theres a great bit of JS for parsing a url here...
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri
...using that you could do (for a google link)...

```
url = parseUri('http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaa.com%2F&ei=g2p1T4u6HcSoiAeO8-DYDg&usg=AFQjCNECtBRRPOF1ooUuuMtNR5y7DSChGQ');
link = unescape(url.queryKey.url);
```

Comment: Hey i wrote this  - still not working - nothing happens on clicking

    var url = parseUri(info.linkUrl);
    var hey = unescape(url.queryKey.url);
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":hey});

Comment: Show me the value of `info.linkUrl` and maybe the value of `hey`

Comment: i've used a chrome.tabs.create on the url hey - nothing opens so i think there's something wrong in the code. how do i get the value?